# Sum Monthly array values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have been trying to get the code to output the data in a certain format so i can use it in a graph chart, and would like to get some help in the final stages. Thanks in advance.

This is my code that produces the below array.

```
    $monthly_sales_array = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($ord as $sales)
    {
        $month_is = date('m-Y',$sales->order_date);
        $monthly_sales_array['months'][$month_is][$i] = $sales->qty*$sales->price_per;
        $i++;
    }

Array
(
[months] => Array
    (
        [07-2014] => Array
            (
                [0] => 33
                [1] => 33
                [2] => 26
                [3] => 26
                [4] => 38.5
                [5] => 33
                [6] => 165                 
            )

        [06-2014] => Array
            (
                [21] => 0.01
                [22] => 44
                [23] => 48
            )
    )
)
```

Trying to get this outcome:

```
Array(
[months] => Array
    (
        [07-2014] => 354.5
        [06-2014] => 92.01
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$monthly_sales_array = array();
$my_array = array(
    'months' => array(
        '07-2014' => array(
                '0' => '33',
                '1' => '33',
                '2' => '26',
                '3' => '26',
                '4' => '38.5',
                '5' => '33',
                '6' => '165' ,                
            ),

        '06-2014' => array(
                '21' => '0.01',
                '22' => '44',
                '23' => '48',
            )
        )
);


foreach ($my_array['months'] as $key => $value) {
    $sum = array_sum(array_map(function ($a) { return $a; }, $my_array['months'][$key]));
    $monthly_sales_array['months'][$key] = $sum;    
}
print_r($monthly_sales_array);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [months] => Array
        (
            [07-2014] => 354.5
            [06-2014] => 92.01
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `foreach`. (there are other ways to do this, but I find this the easiest)

```
foreach($monthly_sales_array['months'] as &$month) {
  $total=0;
  foreach($month as $day) {
    $total+=$day;
  }
  $month=$total;
}
```

Note: the `&` operator in `foreach($monthly_sales_array['months'] as &$month)` means that when you update `$month`, it will be updated in the `$monthly_sales_array`.